# Can I ask anything from a video lecture by providing a lecture link?

Tags: discussion, questions

I was watching a machine learning lecture about SVM from MIT and the lecturer was solving a equation and I do not understand some part of the equation. It seems to me that, there is no way to ask a general question that can answer the problem. It is better to provide the link and specific time (where I can not understand). Can I do this?

Comment: How should users answering it understand it when the video doesn't play?

Comment: I suspect that you should ask this on the Meta of the site where you are thinking of posting your question.

Comment: You can try to break the problem into smaller pieces: if there's an equation on the video, screencap it, then (try to) rewrite the equation in text. If the lecturer was explaining at the same time, quote the lecturer's explanation, then you can finally ask what you don't understand. That way, when the video's gone, the question can be still useful in the future.

Comment: cross-site duplicate: [Should a question that is meaningless without viewing an external link be closed?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266909/839601)

Comment: @meatball I would upvote that again if it was an answer. Great constructive response!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Unfortunately, that would **not** be okay.

Asking folks to watch a video just to understand what you are asking is not reasonable. By saying, *"Watch this video and explain that problem to me",* you are essentially burying the most *crucial* part of your question in a *black box* that cannot possibly be found by others who might be searching for the same problem.

The primary goal of Stack Exchange is to compile a collaborative work of sharing knowledge for those who come after. If you cannot describe the problem, it is going to be impossible for *others* to find what you are asking about through search.

Please do the best you can to describe the problem in your own words and make sure the question makes sense without depending on external links. Those sources can be used to *supplement* your question, but the post should not depend on them to be understood.